# Curious about the use of docker-compose and dockerfile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm studing docker.

docker-compose is known as a role that conveniently runs multiple containers as one script.

First, since Dockerfile only handles one container, is it correct to think that Docker Compose is backwards compatible with Dockerfile?

I thought docker compose could cover everything, but I saw docker compose and docker files used together.

Let's take spring boot as an example.

Can I use only one docker-compose to run the db container required for the application, build the application, check the port being used, and run the jar file?

Or do I have to separate the dockerfils and roles and use the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Docker, there are two concepts: Image and Container.

Images are like mini operating systems stored in a file which is built specifically with our application in mind. Think of it like a custom operating system which is sitting on your hard disk when your computer is switched off.

Containers are running instances of your image.

Imagine you had a shared hard disk (or even CD/DVD if you are old school) which had an operating system which can run on multiple machines. The files on the disk are the "image", and those files running on a machine are a "container".

This is how Docker works, you have files on the machine which are known as the image, and running instances of those files are referred to as the container. Images can also be uploaded and shared for other users to download and run on their machine too.

This brings us to Docker vs Docker Compose.

Docker is the underlying technology which manages (creates, stores or shares) images, and runs containers.

We provide the Dockerfile to tell Docker how to create our images. For example, we say: starts from the Python 3 base image, then install these requirements, then creates these folders, then switch to this user, etc... (I'm oversimplifying the actual steps, but this is just to explain the point).

Once we have done that, we can create an image using Docker, by running docker build .. If you run that, Docker will execute each step in our Dockerfile and store the result as an image on the system.

Once the image is build, you can run it manually using something like this:

docker run <IMAGE_ID>

However, if you need to setup volumes, you need to run them like this:

docker run -v /path/to/vol:/path/to/vol -p 8000:8000 <IMAGE_ID>

Often applications need multiple images to run. For example, you might have an application and a database, and you may also need to setup networks and shared volumes between them.

So you would need to write the above commands with the appropriate configurations and ID's for each container you want to run, every time you want to start your service...

As you might expect, this could become complex, tedious and difficult to manage very quickly...

This is where Docker Compose comes in...

Docker Compose is a tool used to define how Docker runs our images in a yaml file which is can be stored with our code and reused.

So, if we need to run our app image as a container, share port 8000 and map a volume, we can do this:

services:
app:
build:
context: .
ports:
- 8000:8000
volumes:
- app/:/app
Then, every time we need to start our app, we just run docker-compose up, and Docker Compose will handle all the complex docker commands behind the scenes.

So basically, the purpose of Docker Compose is to configure how our running service should work together to serve our application.

When we run docker-compose build, Docker Compose will run all the necessary docker build commands, to build all images needed for our project and tag them appropriately to keep track of them in the system.

In summary, Docker is the underlying technology used to create images and run them as containers, and Docker Compose is a tool that configures how Docker should run multiple containers to serve our application.

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go deeper in what **docker compose** is reading at [Difference between Docker Compose Vs Dockerfile](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/beginners/difference-compose-dockerfile.html#:%7E:text=A%20Dockerfile%20is%20a%20simple,running%20multi-container%20Docker%20applications.&text=It%20get%20an%20app%20running,just%20running%20docker-compose%20up.).

I report part of what explained in the above article:

> A Dockerfile is a simple text file that contains the commands a user could call to assemble an image whereas Docker Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications.
>
> Docker Compose define the services that make up your app in docker-compose.yml so they can be run together in an isolated environment. It get an app running in one command by just running docker-compose up.Docker compose uses the Dockerfile if one add the build command to your project’s docker-compose.yml. Your Docker workflow should be to build a suitable Dockerfile for each image you wish to create, then use compose to assemble the images using the build command.

About your question, I answer you that docker compose is so flexible that you can fragment your **composition logic** in multiple `yaml` files, and combining by the docker compose command line as you need.

Here an example:

```
# Build the docker infrastructure

docker-compose \
  -f network.yaml \
  -f database.yaml \
  -f application.yaml
  build

# Run the application

docker-compose \
  -f application.yaml
  up
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question of spring boot application. you can build complete application through Compose alone as long as you know sequence and dependency but then question will arise are you using the compose power properly? as @Antonio Petricca already given well described answer for the compose

regarding compose file and DockerFile question: it depends on how you wrote your compose file. technically Both are different.
so in short:

```
1- Compose and DockerFile are two different things
2- compose can use multiple modular files even DockerFile and that is why it is so popular, you can break logic into multiple modules then use compose to build it. it also help you debug and iterate faster.
```

Hope its answer your doubt.

Comment: Imperfect analogy: a `Dockerfile` is sort of like `YourApplication.java` -- it says what goes into a reusable image at build time -- but `docker-compose.yml` is like `build.gradle` -- it says what extra pars are needed.  You can use Java without Gradle, or Docker without Compose, and the build/orchestration tool isn't enough on its own to include the contents of the application.